# How do I clear geolocation permissions

Tags: javascript, permissions, geolocation

I want to enable geolocation permissions only once per visit., e.g. if a user leaves my site and then returns, they will be prompted for geolocation permission again.

the `Permissions.revoke` method isn't widely supported, and MDN states that it's [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/revoke).

Answer (score 1):

You can't change permissions of `geolocation`, but u check what was clicked by the user and allow or deny it:

```
 navigator.permissions.query({name:'geolocation'}).then(function(result) {
    if (result.state === 'granted') {

    } else if (result.state === 'prompt') {

    } else if(result.state === 'denied'){

    }
    report(result.state);
  });
```

Comment: The `query result.status`, works on windows , but  updated Firefox-Android checks the global permission status and not the status of the current website. But Android-Chrome looks good.

Answer (score 0):

```
function revokePermission({ 
    navigator.permissions.revoke({
        name:'geolocation'
    }).then(function(result) { 
        report(result.state); 
    }); 
}
```

Here is what u looking for...

Comment: As I stated before, this feature isn't supported by most browsers.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions/revoke#Browser_compatibility